# HttpRequestMessage and Digest Authentication

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, digest-authentication

Is there any built-in function to associate a digest authentication with an HttpRequestMessage in winrt ? Or do I have to use an other class in order to perfom this task ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm using the [`HttpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for an HttpRequest Message. The `HttpClient` constructor accepts a `HttpClientHandler`, which accepts as `Credentials` property an instance of  [`CredentialCache`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.credentialcache%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). A `CredentialCache` should be able to work with digest authentication.

Code should be like:

```
var credCache = new CredentialCache();
credCache.Add(new Uri("http://.com/"),"Digest", new NetworkCredential(UserName,SecurelyStoredPassword,Domain));
var httpClient = new HttpClient( new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credCache});
var answer = httpClient.GetAsync(new Uri("http://request.Uri"));
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this per-request instead of for the entire `HttpClient`?