# Custom DelegatingHandler never return after await base.SendAsync

Tags: c#, async-await, dotnet-httpclient

I'm building an API consumer using HttpClient. Because the provider require the consumer to authenticate using Digest Authentication, so I need to write a custom DelegatingHandler like below:

```
public class DigestAuthDelegatingHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public DigestAuthDelegatingHandler(HttpMessageHandler innerHandler) : base(innerHandler) { }
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)//This line of code is never reached
        {
            //Generate the Digest Authorization header string and add to the request header,
            //then try to resend the request to the API provider
        }
        return response;
    }
}
```

I create a HttpClient and add my custom DelegatingHandler to the message handlers pineline

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new DigestAuthDelegatingHandler(new HttpClientHandler()));            
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/");
HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync("api/getTransactionInfo?TransactionNumber=1000).Result;
```

After doing that, it look like that my consumer runs forever. When I add a break point AFTER the code line await base.SendAsync above, I see that the code will never return, so I have no way to check if the response is get an 401 unauthorized to extract the Digest authorization header details. Nothing wrong at the API provider because I've successfully built another API consumer site using the traditional WebHttpRequest support Digest Authenticate and it works well.

IMPORTANT NOTE: if I switch to write consumer as a Console Application then it works well. So, I'm not sure but I think it's problem related to ASP.NET thread when running in asynchronous mode?

Is there anything wrong I'm doing?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Darrel - most probably, task is faulted and there is no result... you can use explicit continuation to inspect task state - for example,

```
return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        // put the code to check the task state here...
    });
```

On different note, I am not sure if you need to create a custom `DelegatingHandler` for authenticating ... try using `HttpClientHandler` with [Credentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.credentials.aspx) properties (or [UseDefaultCredentials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclienthandler.usedefaultcredentials.aspx) to pass default credentials of current user)

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() {
       PreAuthenticate = true,
       Credentials = new NetworkCredentials(...
   });
```

**EDIT**: Found the example with digest authentication being used with http client using credential cache - see this SO Q & A: [HttpRequestMessage and Digest Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658202/httprequestmessage-and-digest-authentication)

This should solve your actual problem w.r.t. digest authentication without building your own handler.

Comment: The task does not need to fault to get the deadlock.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/01/13/10115163.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My guess is the .Result is blocking the continuation in your handler.  Try changing the .Result to a .ContinueWith

Comment: A even better, use the `await` keyword if available.

Comment: But ASP.NET doesn't use STA threads for responding to web requests, so this doesn't seem likely to be the issue.

Comment: @Andrew Arnott it still has a synchronization context

Answer (score 0):

Having run into this same issue, this is what ended up working for me. The problem was that the endpoint threw a 500 Internal Server Error and thus blocked the thread.

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken)
                         .ContinueWith<HttpResponseMessage>(task =>
        {
            return task.Result;
        });
    }
```

Note that the return inside the anon function returns to the SendAsync function, and then we actually return the Result.