# Call Shopware API from c# with HttpClient

Tags: c#, curl, httpclient, shopware

I'm trying to call the Shopware REST API from c#. Shopware has documentation for calling the API using curl, and mostly I can convert this to c# and HttpClient, but for some options I just don't know what headers to set:

The Shop is behind a basic htaccess-auth and has the Shopware auth using an apikey. My code so far:

```
var handler = new System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler { Credentials = new NetworkCredential(htaccessUsername, htaccessPassword) });
var client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient(handler);

using (var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, apiUrl + "orders?limit=20"))
{
  var encodedStr = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes($"{username}:{apiKey}"));
  var authorizationKey = "Basic" + " " + encodedStr;
  requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationKey);
  // curl_setopt($this->cURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  // curl_setopt($this->cURL, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
  // curl_setopt($this->cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
  // curl_setopt(
  //    $this->cURL,
  //    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,
  //    ['Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8']
  // );
  using (var responseMessage = await client.SendAsync(requestMessage))
  {
    var data = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine(data);
  }
}
```

Basic htaccess auth is working, but the Shopware auth does fail with the following response in data:

```
"{\"success\":false,\"message\":\"Invalid or missing auth\"}"
```

I guess I Need to somehow achieve `curl_setopt($this->cURL, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);` in c#, but I found no clue how to convert These curl options to a header.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the answer for you is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10658202/httprequestmessage-and-digest-authentication):

```
var credCache = new CredentialCache();
var basicCred = new NetworkCredential(htaccessUsername, htaccessPassword);
var digestCred = new NetworkCredential(username, apiKey);
credCache.Add(new Uri("http://.com/"), "Basic", basicCred);
credCache.Add(new Uri("http://.com/"), "Digest", digestCred);
var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credCache });
```

Comment: So I won't need the `requestMessage.Headers.Add("Authorization", authorizationKey);` part anymore? Nice!

Comment: Dang, something is missing, I still get `"{\"success\":false,\"message\":\"Invalid or missing auth\"}"`

Comment: Funky, when I use http instead of https I'll get an html error 401 page as result instead.

Comment: Pity, it looks good, but it does not help.I still get the same error as I would when just sending the basic credentials. The second credentials do not seem to be working.

Comment: Aww, shucks - according to Shopware docs it might not be possible to submit both credentials: https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/faq/#how-can-i-access-the-api-if-my-shop-is-protected-with-a-.htaccess-file?

Comment: But initially you mentioned they offer to connect with combined auth using curl... strange...

Comment: Yeah, they gave me the curl example, but they just copied it somewhere and never checked if it was working :(